# Calculation the percentage-width of div next to floated element

Tags: html, css, css-float

i'm actually can't imagine how engine calculates width of SECTION from [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRg4a/)

It's achieves more expected behavior when `float:left` or `float:right` property add ups to css style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect it to be `70%`, to add up to the `30%` of the `aside`. But to my surprise `100%` seems to do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/wRg4a/1/

The section actually overlaps the left-floating `aside` element. The content of the section moves (shrinks) but the element itself doesn't:

You can see that when you add a bit of CSS to it:

```
border: 5px solid red;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wRg4a/1/

So 50% is 50% of the total width of the body. 100% is 100% of the total width of the body. But 30% of the width of the body is also taken by the aside, so if you specify 50% for the section, then actually only 2/5th (= 20% of the width of the body) is actually visible.

Comment: thanks, well explained. But have you any idea - what's wrong with the question, to get negative rate?

Comment: Not really. Maybe people find it a bit vague.